# Check if the objects of two lists are identical with respect to specific properties and their index

Tags: c#, collections

Consider the following code:

```
class MyType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string DontCare { get; set; }
}

ICollection<MyType> list1 = new List<MyType>();
list1.Add(new MyType { Id = 1, Text = "first", DontCare="one" });
list1.Add(new MyType { Id = 2, Text = "second", DontCare = "two" });

ICollection<MyType> list2 = new List<MyType>();
list2.Add(new MyType { Id = 1, Text = "first", DontCare = "three" });
list2.Add(new MyType { Id = 2, Text = "second", DontCare = "four" });
```

I need to know if the objects in `list1` and `list2` are identical when only considering the properties `Id` and `Text`. Order of the lists is guaranteed, so `list1[0]` only needs to be compared to `list2[0]` and `list1[1]` only to `list2[1]`. How can I do that in C#?

Hint: This is a reduced example, `list1` and `list2` can be arbitrary long (though it's safe to assume they have the same size / short-circuit otherwise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Zip` + `Any` if the index is important as you said:

```
bool anyDifferent = list1
    .Zip(list2, (l1, l2) => (l1, l2))
    .Any(x => x.l1.Id != x.l2.Id || x.l1.Text != x.l2.Text);
```

or with `All` and the opposite logic:

```
bool allIdentical = list1
    .Zip(list2, (l1, l2) => (l1, l2))
    .All(x => x.l1.Id == x.l2.Id && x.l1.Text == x.l2.Text);
```

Both have the same performance since they return the result as soon as possible.